# Can git clone benefit from http2

Tags: git, http2

Can git clone benefit from http2?

I do always prefer ssh over http(s) because of various network errors but also ssh seems to be a bit faster than http(s). So my question is: Could git, especially clone, benefit from http2 s multiplexing functionality for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [smart protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol) over HTTP uses a few long-running requests; HTTP/2 would not benefit dramatically here.

By contrast, the [dumb protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Dumb-Protocol) makes far more separate requests, and could benefit. However:

> The dumb protocol is fairly rarely used these days. It’s difficult to secure or make private, so most Git hosts (both cloud-based and on-premises) will refuse to use it.

In practice, without designing a new protocol to take advantage of HTTP/2, I would expect SSH to continue to give the best results.

Answer (score 1):

This (http2 support) wasn't discussed much in [the mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=git&w=2&r=1&s=http2&q=b).

The [only occurrence](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=142546811716225&w=2) was about a [GSoC 2015 project about git fetch](http://web.archive.org/web/20150516140700/http://git.github.io/SoC-2015-Ideas.html):

> > Due to http limitations and stateless decision, a lot of data is sent
> >     back and forth during have/want negotiation for smart-http. I wonder
> >     if we could implement the "long polling" scheme in a CGI program. The
> >     program terminates HTTP requests and recreates a full duplex
> >     connection for upload-pack to talk to the client. upload-pack falls
> >     back to the normal mode, used by git:// and ssh://.
> >
> > So basically Git-over-TCP-over-HTTP? :)
>
> Yes. The hidden agenda was, if it works well, we might be able to deprecate smart-http one day. That day, if happens, would be in far future though. By that time hopefully we could just use http2 insteadof tcp-over-http1.

So yes, it could benefit Git, but its implementation is not yet actively pursued.