# How to do git checkout on Azure pipeline over HTTP/2?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to set git checkout on HTTP/2. However, I am unable to find any such option and Azure is exclusively setting the http.Version to HTTP/1.1 and this is blocking my checkout due to firewalls. Any help or workaround on how I can set http.Version to HTTP/2 is appreciated. Thank you.

Below is the snapshot of pipeline logs.

[image]

This is my pipeline yaml

```
 pool:
  name: "some pool"

trigger:
- some branch

stages:
- stage: main
  jobs:
  - job: synchronize
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true
      displayName: Git checkout
      continueOnError: true
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: filePath
        filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/sync_git.sh
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

I am running azp agents as container in Kubernetes.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655670/can-git-clone-benefit-from-http2 and https://www.git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol, my first thought was to workout the firewall issue instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't configure the `http.version` in the Checkout step. Microsoft force to use `HTTP/1.1`, you can see it in the [Microsoft agent source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/85c9d3a0e7506d9a4b76cb4f2277991a8fb49797/src/Agent.Plugins/GitSourceProvider.cs):

```
// Force Git to HTTP/1.1. Otherwise IIS will reject large pushes to Azure Repos due to the large content-length header
// This is caused by these header limits - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/headerlimits/
int exitCode_configHttp = await gitCommandManager.GitConfig(executionContext, targetPath, "http.version", "HTTP/1.1");
if (exitCode_configHttp != 0)
{
    executionContext.Warning($"Forcing Git to HTTP/1.1 failed with exit code: {exitCode_configHttp}");
}
```

As workaround, you can disable the native checkout step with `checkout: none` and implement a custom checkout. just add a command line task and perform `git` commands:

```
git config http.version HTTP/2
git clone YOUR-REPO-URL
```